# Jquery Ajax post does not work as expected

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm having this ajax post with should led me to a c# mvc controllerMethod:

```
<script>
$("#save").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/SaveNewPost',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            Address1: "423 Judy Road"
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But when I click my div with the id: #save. The error message in my function gets hit. What could be wrong?

//Thanks

Comment: are you sure url is ok?

Comment: The error-callback function returns three parameters, the second one is a string that might give you a clue what is the problem. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: What is the error message? Parseerror?

Comment: @patrykf Thank you. Typo misstake of me the Url missed a / before Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stringify the data if you set  `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Try this code

```
$("#save").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/SaveNewPost',
        type: 'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify({
            Address1: "423 Judy Road"
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: First of all I made a Typo in my Url. And yes, a had to bring in the JSON.stringify-part also. Tank you! =)